# How do i pass in the object id in a collection as a property in another collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I have built a blog with nodejs,express and ejs with a login and signup setup with passport for authentication. I just want to give users the ability to secure their post i.e allow only them to be able to edit and delete their posts. Finding a way to do this with mongodb has been quite frustrating because i haven't found a definitive way to do this while searching online.

I came across a youtube video that might have the solution:

```
module.exports = {
    ROLE: ROLE,
    users: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Kyle', role: ROLE.ADMIN },
        { id: 2, name: 'Sally', role: ROLE.BASIC },
        { id: 3, name: 'Joe', role: ROLE.BASIC }

    ],
    projects: [
        { id: 1, name: "Kyle's project", userId: 1 },
        { id: 2, name: "Sally's Project", userId: 2 },
        { id: 3, name: "Joe's project", userId: 3 }
    ]
}
```

His logic was based on matching the id property of the users collection with the userId property of the projects collection, which means the userId has to be the same has the id property in users collection.

Is there a way i can set the property a property called usersid  in my blog model to be equal to the id of the id of my logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try with the populate method in mongoose. Creating User and Post schemas and then linking them by adding a property which refers the post owner with the appropriate user. 
Take a look to the documentation! 
[mongoose docs populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)